# Why nodejs cannot inherit as in browser js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, inheritance, new-operator

i have two constructor functions and child one inherits some methods and properties from the parent one it is simply something like this

```
function foo(){
this.bar="baz";
}

function fubar(){
this.qux="zubar";
}
fubar.prototype=new foo();
fubar.prototype.constructor=fubar;
module.exports.fubar=fubar;
```

inside the file inheritance  works fine but when it is exported a cannot reach the elements of the parent 
i have tried `util.inherits` as well the result is the same

Comment: Node complies with the spec, so it should work. Did you forget inside `fubar` to do `foo.call(this)`?

Comment: why is that ? @elclanrs

Comment: That's how you inherit own properties, by calling the constructor with another context.

Comment: anyway it didnt work but when i construct the object before exporting everything works but in this case what is the point of using constructor

Comment: There aren't many reasons to use constructors and inheritance in general, but I don't see how exporting the constructor won't work, something else is not right...

Comment: in my situation it is such simple as here just more methods thats all and strangely doesnt work may be it can be a kinda bug

Comment: Perhaps, but I doubt it is a bug with Node, but rather something else you are not thinking about, or not realizing that it is incorrect. Maybe post your whole code. Also try reproducing your example here http://requirebin.com/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the `foo` constructor from the `fubar` constructor so that the `.bar` property will get properly initialized in the `foo` constructor:

```
function foo(){
    this.bar = "baz";
}

function fubar(){
    foo.call(this);
    this.qux = "zubar";
}
fubar.prototype = Object.create(foo.prototype);
fubar.prototype.constructor = fubar;
module.exports.fubar = fubar;
```

It's also better to use `Object.create()` for the prototype, though what you had would have worked.

Comment: @nikoss - did this work for you and answer your question?